# C# classes init function

Tags: c#, python, class

I am learning c#, having used python before, and i have started to use classes in my work.

Python has the `__init__()` function to initialise a class, for example:

```
class name():

    __init__(self):

        # this code will run when the class is first made
```

Is there a similar function for c# classes?

currently, I am creating a normal function inside the class and having to call it straight after it is made.

Comment: Have you read about constructors or object-initalizers? Just some research would be good.

Comment: Have a look at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use one or more constructor for that:
[see this link on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors).

For example:

```
public class Person
{
    private string last;
    private string first;

    // This constructor is called a default constructor.
    // If you put nothing in it, it will just instanciate an object
    // and set the default value for each field: for a reference type,
    // it will be null for instance. String is a reference type, 
    // so both last and first will be null.
    public Person()
    {}

    // This constructor will instanciate an object an set the last and first with string you provide.
    public Person(string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        last = lastName;
        first = firstName;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // last and first will be null for myPerson1.
       Person myPerson1 = new Person();

       // last = Doe and first = John for myPerson2.
       Person myPerson2 = new Person("Doe", "John");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your talking about constructor in c#

```
class MyClass{

public MyClass{ //this is the constructor equals to pythons init
}

}
```

These concepts are available in almost all languages with different format

Answer (score 0):

You should start building a constructor like this:

```
public class Car
{
   public string plateNumber {get; set;}

   public Car(string platenumber)
   {
     this.plateNumber = platenumber;
   }
}
```

And then initialize an instance of it in another form or class like so:

```
Car myCar = new Car("123abc");
```